# AFNetworking 2.0 and navigation controller

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uinavigationcontroller, afnetworking-2

I use `UINavigationController` and I push a view controller which has an object of class which is responsible to make some GET requests. If I press the back button while the request is active, I have to wait until the request get finished. I have found that the functions `viewWillDisappear` and `viewDidDisappear` are called only when the request is finished. I want to immediately pop the viewController when the user presses the back button. Is this possible?
The code I use for GET request is :

```
NSString *urlJson=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://test.com"];
    manager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlJson]];
    [manager setRequestSerializer:[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer]];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializerWithReadingOptions:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments];
    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"text/html"];

    [manager GET:urlJson parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        NSDictionary *jsonDict = (NSDictionary *) responseObject;

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
     {
         NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
     }];
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: hmm, it seems strange that the request has to finish before 'viewWillDisappear' is called... is this a _synchronous_ or _asynchronous_ request? are you sure the problem isn't somewhere else?

Comment: It should be asynchronous request because the download task is inside block. However I have found that while the request is running the main thread is blocked and the UI doesn't respond to actions. May the problem is because the AFNetworking code is part of another class?